# programmatically parallelizing portions of a C program

Tags: c, macos, unix, parallel-processing

I have a small *number-crunching* portion of a much larger program, which appears as execution bottleneck; it computes and writes data sequences to arbitrary locations of individual buffers and sums the results. By monitoring the cpu performance I can see everything getting executed on one cpu core while the remaining cores stay idle.

What can I do to make sure all doesn't end in the same processor core while others stay idle?

Is there an example of how to deal with this in OSX (Darwin UNIX, or BSD), without having to use Cocoa code and/or Apple (or any other) proprietary libraries?

Here is the code I'd like to parallelize, simplified as two-segment work, for convenience of making my point. Functions **work1A()** and **work1B()** may run in parallel on two different cpu cores, since what's happening in **work1B()** doesn't depend on what's going on in **work1A()** and vice versa. They only share last three arguments, which don't get modified:

```
//___________________________________________________
void work1 (Float32 start, Float32 len, Float32 R, parameters** params)
{
long values = (long)R*len;
Float32* fBuffer;
Float32* fBuffA;
Float32* fBuffB;  

fBuffer = calloc(values, sizeof(Float32));
fBuffA  = calloc(values, sizeof(Float32));
fBuffB  = calloc(values, sizeof(Float32));

//begin of parallelizable code
work1A(fBuffA, start, len, params);
work1B(fBuffB, start, len, params);
//end of parallelizable code

for(long val = 0; val < values; val++)
    fBuffer[val] = fBuffA[val] + fBuffB[val];

showResult(start, len, R, fBuffer);

free(fBuffA);
free(fBuffB);    
free (fBuffer);
return;
}
//___________________________________________________
```

I'd prefer not having to interfer with the program's main function and other functions being called upon, which have pre-defined threading policies of their own. RAM usage is not a major concern. I hope not needing to re-write a 20000 line program from ground up, just because of this small portion. Thanks in advance!

**I'm trying to improve the post.** Being grateful to user **dmg** for pointing me at **OpenMP**, and showing how simple it can be when it works, I regrettably find that OS X/Darwin has a long and oscillating history of only partial OpenMP support. As don't see how I can afford contributing in making this history better, I'm also considering a different scenario, using *p_threads*.

Here I encounter two problems:

1. Two threads still don't imply the system will understand putting those threads on two cores in parallel.
2. I don't know how to pass four arguments to each of the thread containing functions **work1()** and **work2()**, two of which happen to be arrays, without rewriting a substantial part of my program, which deals with internal data representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes one possible answer which functions according to my own research, although it involves adapting a portion of originally posted source-code in the following way. I keep it simple for reading convenience, but if a piece of code can evidently get parallelized, this will most likely fix it. More elaborate code of better programming practice can easily be derived from it.

```
#include <pthread.h>
//variables which shouldn't be declared on the stack!
float R, start, len;
Float32* fBuffA;
Float32* fBuffB; 
Float32* fBuffer;
//___________________________________________________
void work (Float32 start, Float32 len)
{
int result;
int num = 2;
pthread_t threads[num];
int thread_args[num];
int rc;
void* rp;    

long values = (long)R*len;

fBuffer = calloc(values, sizeof(Float32));
fBuffA  = calloc(values, sizeof(Float32));
fBuffB  = calloc(values, sizeof(Float32));

//begin of parallelizable code
rc = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, synLT, (void *) &thread_args[0]);
rc = pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, synRT, (void *) &thread_args[1]);
rc = pthread_join(threads[0], &rp);
rc = pthread_join(threads[1], &rp);
//end of parallelizable code

for(long val = 0; val < values; val++)
    fBuffer[val] = fBuffA[val] + fBuffB[val];

result = fbshow(start, len);
free(fBuffA);
free(fBuffB);    
free (fBuffer);
return;
}
```

The workA() and workB() functions got modified in the following way to comply with pthread specification and syntax:

```
//___________________________________________________
void *workA  (void *A)
{
int tid;
tid = *((int *) A);
doSomething();
int *ret = calloc(1,sizeof(int));
*ret = 42;
return (void*)ret;
}
//___________________________________________________
void *workB  (void *B)
{
int tid;
tid = *((int *) B);
doSomethingElse();
int *ret = calloc(1,sizeof(int));
*ret = 42;
return (void*)ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/) as it is rather simple and non-intrusive:

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none)
#pragma omp single 
{
    #pragma omp task
    work1A(fBuffA, start, len, params);

    #pragma omp task
    work1B(fBuffB, start, len, params);

    #pragma omp taskwait
}
```

Just compile with `-fopenmp` if you use `gcc`, add `#include <omp.h>`, and do the following:

```
$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
$ ./myexe
```

Not to mention, that if you compile without `-fopenmp` you will still get valid single-threaded code. To check if you've compiled correctly, put a call like:

```
printf("Thread ID %d in work1A\n", omp_get_thread_num());
```

and:

```
printf("Thread ID %d in work1B\n", omp_get_thread_num());
```

To see if you they are truly ran by two different threads. And it's only 5 lines of code and 2 parens.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and plausible reply!
Here are still some problems, though:

if using GCC4.2, build fails, I get following errors:
#pragma omp parallel default(none)     -> Encolsing parallel
work1(fBuf1, start, len, params)       -> start not specified in enclosing parallel
                                       -> len not specitied in enclosing parallel
                                       -> fBuf1 not specitied in enclosing parallel.

If using Apple LLVM, no errors, but gives only a valid single threaded code.

Comment: Also, instructions such as:
printf("Thread ID %d in work1A\n", omp_get_thread_num());
give error messages about illegal implicit declarations.
I must be missing something obvious (importing headers, etc…);
Including the header "/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/omp.h" still gives the warning
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/local/lib/libgomp.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

Comment: It also gives this error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_omp_get_thread_num", referenced from:
      _work in work.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). Sorry for having to split the comment into three parts, "max number of characters" made me do so.

Comment: @user3078414 Oh, sorry, forgot to mention that you should add `#include <omp.h>`. Added it to the answer.

Comment: @user3078414 As for the linker error, why don't you try installing OpenMP [from source](http://clang-omp.github.io/#try-openmp-clang)

Comment: Thanks, I have also figured it out myself, as might have been seen from my former comment. As explained in the comment, the problem unfortunately still persists. (-:

Comment: Installing OpenMP from source - that's exactly what I have already done. I work on a machine with 10.7, 10.8 and 10.10, including all SDKs 10.6-10.10. Are there perhaps other system and SDK constraints? I'm not sure how well it is supported in OSX/Darwin? Also, as this appears to be an optional API, can a program complied with OpenMP support work properly in environments which don't have the exact and fine-tuned versions of OpenMP installed?

Comment: You can freely distribute an executable with the openmp library.